# Putting value into array object using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to produce something like this

```
album = {[
 name:'',
image:'',
tracks:[]
],[
 name:'',
image:'',
tracks:[]
]}
```

But now I'm stuck at appending the value into the right json object.

```
var albums = {};

$.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1rQX6kg84TqcwGtZHYIdn4/albums", function(data, status) {
  tempArr = [];
  $.each(data.items, function(i, obj) {

    tempArr.push(obj.images[0].url);
    albums['image'] = tempArr;
  });

  console.log(albums)

});
```

You can see the albumn data here http://jsfiddle.net/u5me8csx/1
Any help?

Comment: You need an array of object's isn't it... then your structure above is wrong

Comment: what is the structure of the value returned by the api

Comment: there is no track info in the data?

Comment: @ArunPJohny updated my question. Added link.

Comment: what about the track value?

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/buk0qvda/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in the question for the `albums` object is wrong, you have swapped the brackets used for object and array notations.

You can use Array.map() to iterate over the items and create the desired format like

```js
$.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1rQX6kg84TqcwGtZHYIdn4/albums", function(data, status) {
  var albums = data.items.map(function(item) {
    return {
      name: item.name,
      image: item.images[0],
      tracks: []
    }
  });
  console.log(albums);
  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(albums, null, 2))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: wow I didn't know can use map. You can use map whenever you want? I think it very depends on how the response structure look like right? Can you do a version of non-map? I want to learn how to put arrays to an object in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @Jennifer you are putting objects to an array... `items` is an array of object, we are using the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to convert each item in the map to a different format and return a new array of those objects

Comment: array of objects mean? and is there anything called object array? I'm confused. Like `{name:['abc','def']}` is object of array or array of object?

Comment: `{}` is used for object notation and `[]` is for array... so the above one is an object which as a property called name whose value is an array. An array of objects will be `[{name: 'x'}, {name: 'y'}, {name: 'z'}]`

Comment: if it's like this `{'something':['a','b']}`, does it called object of arrays?

Comment: @Jennifer there is nothing calling object of arrays... object is singular... an object can have arrays as its property value